# Looking for formula for google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet in which I have a status column. I want to change the value of the status column based on the other three column values like changing the status from PENDING TO PROCESSED when ORDER ID is updated in 1st Column, change the status from PROCESSED to SHIPPED when value is updated in 2nd Column and change the status from SHIPPED to DELIVERED when the date is updated in 3rd column.

Comment: Have you seen the `IF` formula?

Comment: Put few sample data then explain what you want.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lzLYr58GUNQNIt752tQEa2wB2MZKdKFpnLLX98Ja2LY/edit

When data is entered in A2 the status will be PENDING.
when data is entered in B2, the status will be PROCESSED.
when data is entered in C2, the status will be SHIPPED.
when data is entered in D2, the status will be DELIVERED.

Comment: access in denied!

Comment: Acces given. Please recheck

Comment: @MuhammadAsim - Access denied.

Comment: please check again, access has been given to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
=if(D2<>"","DELIVERED",if(C2<>"","SHIPPED",if(B2<>"","PROCESSING","PENDING")))
```